# Screenshot of a View is not has the same size as the view?

Tags: android, kotlin, view

So, I'm trying to blur out my `ContraintLayout` what approach I took is

1. Take a screenshot of the root view.
2. Add an `ImageView` in the root view with layout param `MATCH_PARENT` and `MATCH_PARENT`.
3. Blur that screenshot
4. Set the screenshot bitmap to this `ImageView`.

But it's not working as expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is some relevant code I'm using.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val imageView = ImageView(this)
        val param = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        imageView.layoutParams = param
        val bit = convertViewToBitmap(root)
        val blurred = blur(bit,25F)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(blurred)
        root.addView(imageView)
    }
```

**To get the screenshot of a View**

```
private fun convertViewToBitmap(view: View): Bitmap {
        val spec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        view.measure(spec, spec)
        view.layout(0, 0, view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight)
        val b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val c = Canvas(b)
        //c.translate((-view.scrollX).toFloat(), (-view.scrollY).toFloat())
        view.draw(c)
        return b
    }
```

**To blur that ScreenShot**

```
 var times = 0

    fun blur(bitmap: Bitmap, radius: Float): Bitmap? {
        val renderScript = RenderScript.create(this)
        val blurredBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
        val input: Allocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
            renderScript,
            blurredBitmap,
            Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL,
            Allocation.USAGE_SHARED
        )
        val output: Allocation = Allocation.createTyped(renderScript, input.type)
        // Load up an instance of the specific script that we want to use.
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript)).apply {
            setInput(input)
            setRadius(radius)
            forEach(output)
        }
        output.copyTo(blurredBitmap)
        if (times < 5) {
            times += 1
            blur(blurredBitmap, radius)
        }
        return blurredBitmap
    }
```

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.20" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the result
[image]

Comment: what actually is the problem, taking the screenshot, blurring it, or setting its bitmap to the ImageView?

Comment: @afhamu check update.

Comment: so you want the blurred view to be of the same size as the original view?

Comment: @afhamu yes man, I want the hello world to be blurred. It is just a sample there would be lot of view inside that root view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the screenshot of the view and blurring it. try this:

1. Blur the `TextView` using `BlueMaskFilter`

   ```
    float radius = yourTextView.getTextSize() / 3; 
    BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    yourTextView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
   ```
2. Convert the blurred `TextView` to `BitMap` and set it to the `ImageView` bitmap

Comment: The thing is that I put the text view as an example. It might have multiple views.